# Appendix name (Anhang/Appendix) not appearing, despite title option

Tags: koma-script, appendices

I have a strange issue where the title option doesn't seem to work properly. I included the package as follows:

```
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
```

Then in the document, i am including the appendices as follows:

```
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Abbildungen}
    \chapter{Auflistungen}
\end{appendices}
```

**The toc ends up fine as expected:**

Anhang A Abbildungen

Anhang B Auflistungen

**But in the body, the space where the word "Anhang" should be is made, but it doen't appear.**

A Abbildungen

[...]

B Auflistungen

---

I have no idea why. I have already tried several combinations of the package options, and commands, and also tried to rename the `\appendixname` in case its empty or sth.

I am using koma-scripts scrrept-class if that does matter.

Comment: Can you put those information you just gave into some minimal compilable code? Without it, anything will be guesswork.

Answer (score 6):

You can find a suggestion by Markus Kohm on [komascript.de](http://www.komascript.de/node/1766).

```
% see http://www.komascript.de/node/1766
\documentclass[headings=appendixprefix]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providecommand*{\appendixmore}{}% Falls Option headings=appendixprefix nicht verwendet wurde.
\newcommand*{\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry}{}
\appto\appendixmore{%
  \let\SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
  \renewcommand*{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{}{% Eintrag ohne Nummer
      \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{}{#2}%
    }{% Eintrag mit Nummer
      \SavedOriginaladdchaptertocentry{}{\appendixname~#1\autodot\enskip#2}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\appendix
\chapter{Abbildungen}
\Blindtext[20]
\chapter{Auflistungen}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

KOMA-Script provides all the features of the package appendix. So don't use this package under a KOMA-Script class.

The appendix is not an environment, it's a command. Just write `\appendix` at its start.

The KOMA-Script manual has a lot of documentation about the appendix.